# PayPal return page problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, payment-gateway

On payPal I added return page URL where user is redirected when payment is finished.

```
http://somewhere/back.aspx
```

But when I return from payPal after payment I don't get `'tx'` or anything in queryString, what could  be reason for that? I use correct token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot rely on the returnurl parameter for getting back any information about the PayPal transaction, those would be to easy to change.

You need to implement Instant Payment Notification (IPN) so you will get all the variables returned, here is an example : https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/ipn-codesamples-pop-outside

Comment: Do you want to say that if I want to use PDT I have to implement IPN too?

Comment: No. IPN and PDT are two separate features. One doesn't require the other.